# SQL: Creating a common table from multiple similar tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have multiple databases on a server, each with a large table where most rows are identical across all databases. I'd like to move this table to a shared database and then have an override table in each application database which has the differences between the shared table and the original table.

The aim is to make updating and distributing the data easier as well as keeping database sizes down.

**Problem constraints**

The table is a hierarchical data store with date based validity.

```
table DATA (
    ID int primary key,
    CODE nvarchar,
    PARENT_ID int foreign key references DATA(ID),
    END_DATE datetime,
    ...
)
```

Each unique CODE in DATA may have a number of rows, but at most a single row where END_DATE is null or greater than the current time (a single valid row per CODE). New references are only made to valid rows.

Updating the shared database should not require anything to be run in application databases. This means any override tables are final once they have been generated.

Existing references to DATA.ID must point to the same CODE, but other columns do not need to be the same. This means any current rows can be invalidated if necessary and multiple occurrences of the same CODE may be combined.

PARENT_ID references must have same parent CODE before and after the split. The actual PARENT_ID value may change if necessary.

The shared table is updated regularly from an external source and these updates need to be reflected in each database's DATA. CODEs that do not appear in the external source can be thought of as invalid, new references to these will not be added.

Existing functionality will continue to use DATA, so the new view (or alternative) must be transparent. It may, however, contain more rows than the original provided earlier constraints are met.

New functionality will use the shared table directly.

Select performance is a concern, insert/update/delete is not.

The solution needs to support SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Possible solution**

```
-- in a single shared DB
DATA_SHARED (table)

-- in each app DB
DATA_SHARED (synonym to DATA_SHARED in shared DB)
DATA_OVERRIDE (table)
DATA (view of DATA_SHARED and DATA_OVERRIDE)
```

Take an existing DATA table to become DATA_SHARED.

Exclude IDs with more than one possible CODE so only rows common across all databases remain. These missing rows will be added back once the data is updated the first time.

Unfortunately every DATA_OVERRIDE will need all rows that differ in any table, not only rows that differ between DATA_SHARED and the previous DATA. There are several IDs that differ only in a single database, this causes all other databases to inflate. Ideas?

This solution causes DATA_SHARED to have a discontinuous ID space. It's a mild annoyance rather than a major issue, but worth noting.

**edit:** I should be able to keep all of the rows in DATA_SHARED, just invalidate them, then I only need to store differing rows in DATA_OVERRIDE.

I can't think of any situations where PARENT_ID references become invalid, thoughts?

Before:

```
DB1.DATA
ID | CODE | PARENT_ID | END_DATE
1  | A    | NULL      | NULL
2  | A1   | 1         | 2020
3  | A2   | 1         | 2010

DB2.DATA
ID | CODE | PARENT_ID | END_DATE
1  | A    | NULL      | NULL
2  | X    | NULL      | NULL
3  | A2   | 1         | 2010
4  | X1   | 2         | NULL
5  | A1   | 1         | 2020
```

After initial processing (DATA_SHARED created from DB1.DATA):

```
SHARED.DATA_SHARED
ID | CODE | PARENT_ID | END_DATE
1  | A    | NULL      | NULL
3  | A2   | 1         | 2010

-- END_DATE is omitted from DATA_OVERRIDE as every row is implicitly invalid
DB1.DATA_OVERRIDE
ID | CODE | PARENT_ID
2  | A1   | 1

DB2.DATA_OVERRIDE
ID | CODE | PARENT_ID
2  | X    |
4  | X1   | 2
5  | A1   | 1
```

After update from external data where A1 exists in source but X and X1 don't:

```
SHARED.DATA_SHARED
ID | CODE | PARENT_ID | END_DATE
1  | A    | NULL      | NULL
3  | A2   | 1         | 2010
6  | A1   | 1         | 2020
```

**edit:** The DATA view would be something like:

```
select D.ID, ...
from DATA D
left join DATA_OVERRIDE O on D.ID = O.ID
where O.ID is null
union all
select ID, ...
from DATA_OVERRIDE
order by ID
```

Given the small number of rows in DATA_OVERRIDE, performance is good enough.

**Alternatives**

I also considered an approach where instead of DATA_SHARED sharing IDs with the original DATA, there would be mapping tables to link DATA.IDs to DATA_SHARED.IDs. This would mean DATA_SHARED would have a much cleaner ID-space and there could be less data duplication, but the DATA view would require some fairly heavy joins. The additional complexity is also a significant negative.

**Conclusion**

Thank you for your time if you made it all the way to the end, this question ended up quite long as I was thinking it through as I wrote it. Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: So the question is how to merge table with hierarchical data, isn't it?

Comment: The question is what is the best way to split multiple large tables into a single large table and multiple small ones. The merging itself is simple enough.

Comment: I'm not so sure, merging hierarchical data - is the case of rocket science (if you want to get something meaningful). And to get the meaningful differences (am I right thinking that "small tables" are differences) is just another view on this problem.

Comment: Partitioning should be used to split large table to small partitions and UNION View should be used to view many tables as one.

Comment: I've added my view implementation to the post in case it's worth commenting on.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij I probably misunderstood what you meant about merging, if you have any details about it, I'd like to look into it.

Comment: @jbaliuka the table isn't quite big enough to require partitioning, but is big enough to warrant moving to a shared DB.